# Android: sharing Intent calls onStop only for some targets

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm launching an `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`, with the purpose of sharing a file with an external application. After starting the `Intent`, I'm using the `onStop` method of my `Fragment` to run some logic.

I've noticed some choices in the share dialog result in calls to `onStop` (always) and others don't (never). For example, choosing Gmail calls `onStop`, but choosing Drive doesn't.

This occurs with both `Intent.createChooser` with the share dialog, and a plain `Intent` that shows the normal resolver.

I want to avoid `onPause`, since it triggers in some cases that don't suit my purposes.

Why is this happening? How can I ensure my `Fragment` always stops when it's no longer visible?

Comment: An addition: after looking at the `ActivityManager` logs, **I think** the application that doesn't result in `onStop` is using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT` (`0x80000`). Flags I set into the Intent don't prevent this.

Comment: Please do not use a comment to add info. Just edit your post.

Comment: It is quite normal that your activity gets killed if you start another intent. Use onSaveInstanceState to save .. your state.

Comment: This doesn't have to do with state. There's no state involved. Actually, if my Activity was being killed when starting the new Intent, I probably wouldn't have this problem. If this is not clear, I may clarify the question.